# How to specify an object to be locked in java using Lock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Using the synchronized(intrinsic locking) keyword for locking, we could do something like:

```
public void addSum(int a) {
   synchronized(q) {
     q.add(a); // q is say a Queue
   }
}
```

In the above code say when an object tries to call the addSum() method i.e. x.addSum(10), the lock will be held on 'q' and not x. So using synchronization we could lock an object which is other than the actual calling object(Class).

Below I'm using Lock from java concurrent package, is there a way to specify which object should the lock be on (i.e like in the above code snippet using synchronized it was specified that the lock/synchronization should be on 'q'). However below when I'm using Lock, I haven't specified on which object should the lock be on. Can it be done?

```
public void addSum(int a) {
   lock.tryLock();
   q.add(a);
   lock.unlock();
 }
```

I did refer - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html . However was looking for much smaller example to clear my concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `Lock` objects don't work the same way as `synchronized`. `synchronized` cannot start within a method invocation and reach outside that method invocation. The pattern you've shown

```
lock.tryLock();
q.add(a);
lock.unlock();
```

would only be possible if the opposite were true. `Lock` objects typically work by flipping on/off a switch/flag atomically, indicating they've acquired or released the lock.

Comment: Oh when I say q.add(a) its actually not calling itself. Its the add method in the queue. I changed the other method name to addSum. So the code snippet I showed for synchronization is actually not starting and ending in different methods.

Comment: So when I'm using Lock in the above code snippet which object is it locking on? In case synchronization code snippet it was locking on 'q'.

Comment: @srock First comment: Syntactically works `synchronized` as a _block of code_, either nested in a method or spanning the full method. You acquire the lock at the beginning of the block and you release it at the end. A `Lock` object's lock, however, can span multiple _blocks of code_, in and out of of method calls, and potentially (dangerously) never be released.

Comment: @srock Second comment: That depends on the implementation. Take `ReentrantLock` for example, it doesn't _lock_ on anything. It uses a technique called compare-and-swap to atomically set a flag that indicates a particular threads as an owner.

Comment: First comment reply agree. Second comment: so what I understand is it depends in which type of lock impl it is.

Comment: @srock Yes and no. Yes, different implementations can use different techniques for locking. No, none of them will be able to `synchronize` on some instance and maintain that synchronization across method invocations.

Comment: Cool. So none of the 'Lock' Impl allows to lock on a object. Only synchronizing (using keyword Synchronize - intrinsic lock) allows to lock on a object. And also that means if I use Synchronized keyword on a method to provide synchronization, multiple threads could simultaneously access the same method as long as the methods are called by different objects. However with 'Lock' impl its one and only 1 thread accessing the method (unless the number of threads are specified as while using say semaphore)

Comment: @srock You can consider `Lock` objects as the lock objects themselves. But the process is completely different from `synchronized` which involves object monitors. `synchronized` on an instance method will lock on the calling instance. If you're invoking the method on different instances, they won't block each other. If, instead, they use the same `Lock` instance to lock, they will block each other.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. One more follow-up question. So based on my code snippet using lock - I do x.addSum(10) on Thread T1, at the same time I also do y.addSum(20), I would assume y.addSum() will have to wait until x.addSum is completed. Correct? However when using object monitor - synchronized keyword it wouldn't block y.addSum even if it is x.addSum was being executed since the synchronization of on instance.

Comment: @srock If they `share` the `lock` object, one will wait for the other. Similarly, if they share the object used in the `synchronized` block`, one thread will wait for the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what the word "lock" means.  Suppose this method is called:

```
void foobar() {
    synchronized(x) {
        y.doSomething();
    }
}
```

We say that `x` is "locked" while the thread is in the `y.doSomething()` call, but that does *not* prevent other threads from accessing fields or updating fields of `x`.  The `synchronized` keyword means one thing, and one thing only.

The JVM will not allow two threads to synchronize on the same object at the same time.

That's *all* it means.  How you use it is up to you.  My example is using it to prevent `y.doSomething()` from being called in more than one thread at the same time, but it only works if every call to `y.doSomething()` is protected in the same way, and it only works if `x` always refers to the same object.

The java.util.concurrent.ReentrantLock class works much the same way.  The only guarantee that the JVM makes is that no two threads can "lock" the same ReentrantLock object at the same time.  That's all it does.  The rest is up to you.

---

P.S., Your second example does not test the value returned by `lock.tryLock()`.  That's a mistake.  If lock.tryLock() returns false, that means it failed to lock the lock.

Comment: Perfect. Towards the end you have mentioned that I'm not checking the boolean returned by lock.try lock(), so in the code snippet I posted above if the lock is not available the thread will still try add the integer to the queue 'q'? Is that correct. So basically its going to add to the queue 'q' irrespective of lock object?